# Selecting first header in a defined container but not first-child

Tags: css

Consider the following HTML.

```
<div class="definedOuter">
  <div>
    <div class="maybe some classes">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div>
        <h2>Other Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how many elements may be inside of `.definedOuter` but I know inside of there, I want to apply CSS the very first `<h>` inside of that `.definedOuter`.

`:first-child` and `:first-of-type` don't appear to work, as they are based on the selected elements parent, not some arbitrary element. Currently I am applying a class to the first `<h>` tag and doing a `.definedOuter .class` selector, but I'd like to not have to need a class.

Is there any CSS magic to select that `<h>` tag?

Added a fiddle for clarity I hope. https://jsfiddle.net/ezff01ap/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `>` operator to make it a little more precise.

```css
.definedOuter > div > div > h2:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="definedOuter">
  <div>
    <div class="aClass">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div>
        <h2>Other Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

If you have a class on the `div` that is a parent of the header you can use the same operator like so:

```css
.definedOuter div.aClass > h2:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="definedOuter">
  <div>
    <div class="aClass">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div>
        <h2>Other Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But OP mentioned "***I don't know how many elements may be inside of `.definedOuter`***". This assumes there will always and only be two divs before the first heading.

Comment: Correct. There are an unknown number of levels between the outer and the first header.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. Is the new assumption I made correct?

Comment: If I have a class...  what if I don't.

Comment: Well then that makes it much harder. Would you be opposed to using javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I see no CSS way to do it.
With jQuery you can do smth like

```
$(".definedOuter h2").first().css("color","red");
```